# Check if a (internal) function / feature / command exists in MariaDB / MySQL

Tags: php, mariadb, nette

I use [MEDIAN](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/median/) function in my app. When I deploy it on the production server, I get `Syntax error` because there is an older version of MariaDB.

Is there a way to check if a certain function exists? Someting like [function_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) in PHP?

I can check the version like this `SELECT VERSION();` and maintain some list of functions and versions. But I'm looking for simpler and more universal solution.

Now I do it like this:

```php
// PHP + NETTE framework

$sqlVersionOK = $this->checkSqlServerVersion([10,3,3]); 

if ($sqlVersionOK) { /* ... */ } else { /* ... */ }

public function checkSqlServerVersion(array $nums):bool {
    
    $version = $this->repository->query('SELECT VERSION() AS num;')->fetch();

    $version = explode('.', $version->num);
    $ver = array_map(function ($item) { return (int) filter_var($item, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); }, $version);
    
    if ($ver[0] > $nums[0]) { return TRUE; } // major number is bigger
    elseif($ver[0]==$nums[0] and $ver[1] >= $nums[1]) { return TRUE; } // major number is the same, minor is bigger or same
    elseif($ver[0]==$nums[0] and $ver[1] == $nums[1] and $ver[2] >= $nums[1]) { return TRUE; } // major and minor numbers are the same, patch is bigger or same
    else { return FALSE; } 
    
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well the best solution would be to use the same versions of relevant software on BOTH test and live environments. That afterall is what dev/uat/live environments are supposed to be otherwise the dev and test process is kinda wasted

Comment: Thanks for your opinion @RiggsFolly, but that doesn't exactly help me. In this case, these things are not in my power to change. I just need to find out if the command is available or not.

Comment: So what are you going to do if the function is not available?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: In this case I set variable to NULL and display something like "this number is not available". There will be no error messages and it'll start working when they upgrade their server. The same app is running on the other server where everything is OK.

Comment: Since you are using Nette Framework, you can test if function will return error or not during container built. That way you will have that information later during normal app run.

Answer (score 0):

10.6 added [information_schema.keywords](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-keywords-table/) however its not early enough for you. (And I'm not sure it covers all functions).

Given MEDIAN is a 10.3+ Window function, and Window Functions where only added in 10.2 gives a very limited Window (pun intended) of when an alternate can be found.

[Stored aggregate functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/stored-aggregate-functions/) where only added in 10.3 also so that isn't a possibility to create a SQL function equivalent in 10.2.

MariaDB has a [executable comment syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/comment-syntax/) where some function are only executed if the server is of sufficient version, e.g.:

```
/*M!100303 SELECT MEDIAN(star_rating) OVER (PARTITION BY name) FROM book_rating */
```

And this will be an empty query on 10.2 instances.

A more pragmatic answer however is:

- Run the same version in production as your test/development environment
- As even 10.3 just reached its [end of upstream maintaince](https://mariadb.org/about/#maintenance-policy) take the opportunity to upgrade to a newer version and gain all the benefits without spending too much time coding alternatives on unmaintained software.

Comment: Thanks. So in general the answer is: there is no simple way to check if a certain internal function exists in MariaDB.

Comment: Pretty much at the moment.